# is it possible to replace a ms-dos command with another one?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, unix, emacs

I installed msys tools for a c++ programming more unix-like environment. the find command won't replace the native find windows command, which is pretty sad because I have to type in the full path (absolute) to the find msys command to use it.
But which is really annoying because I am using emacs 'grep-find' command and it will use the find ms-dos command and will give an anarchic and useless result.

Is it possible to replace the native find windows command somehow ?

Comment: If the commands are not built-in, they are implemented with a distinct executable which is searched in the PATH; so it would only be a matter of putting the directory with the Unix-like commands before the standard Windows directories in the PATH variable.

Comment: Are you trying to make the 'find' command run a different program, or do you want to be able to type something other than "find" to run the 'find' command?